# How to display the image with pop up in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display the pop up when click the link button from the grid view in asp.net. In the database I store the image with the byte type. I write the code in HTML for

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvImage" DataKeyNames="File_ID" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="File_ID" HeaderText="ID"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="File_Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="Server" Text="View" CommandName="View"
                    OnClick="View_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkdelete" runat="server" 
                    OnClick="lnkdelete_Click">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
</asp:GridView>
```

When I click the view buttton the page is load but the image is not displayed and then none of the error is occur.

Answer (score 0):

To display image in popup : on the pop up, pass the record id from the parent page as query string and get this id on popup page, convert the Byte to Image and display it in Image tag